# Golang database/sql MYSQL 8 db.Query inconsistency

Tags: mysql, go

Found a strange inconsistency upon selecting rows from mysql 8.0.19 after some transaction on resultset (e.g. at mysqlworkbench by editing some rows).

(for reference this function: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query)

In others words `db.Query(SQL)` returns the old state of my resultset (before editing and committing).

**MYSQL rows before editing:**

```
105 admin
106 user1
107 user2
109 user3
```

**MYSQL rows after editing:**

```
105 admin
106 user11
107 user22
109 user33
```

**But Golang `db.Query(SQL)` still continuously returns:**

```
105 admin
106 user1
107 user2
109 user3
```

Does `db.Query(SQL)` require being committed to maintain consistency with current database state? Because after I have added `db.Begin()` and `db.Commit()` it started to work consistently. Haven't tried other databases, doesn't look like a driver issue, or variable copy issue. It is bit odd coming from JDBC. Autocommit disabled.

The code:

```
func FindAll(d *sql.DB) ([]*usermodel.User, error) {
    const SQL = `SELECT * FROM users t ORDER BY 1`
    //tx, _ := d.Begin()
    rows, err := d.Query(SQL)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    defer func() {
        err := rows.Close()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
    }()

    l := make([]*usermodel.User, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
        t := usermodel.NewUser()
        if err = rows.Scan(&t.UserId, &t.Username, &t.FullName, &t.PasswordHash, &t.Email, &t.ExpireDate,
            &t.LastAuthDate, &t.StateId, &t.CreatedAt, &t.UpdatedAt); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        l = append(l, t)
    }

    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    //_ = tx.Commit()

    return l, nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is purely about MySQL MVCC (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) and not Go/DB driver.

In short, if you start a transaction, read some data, then another transaction changes it and commits, you may or may not see the results, depending on the transaction isolation level set on the MySQL server.